# React shallow render unit test with filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, filesaver.js

I would like to test a component that uses filesaver.js in one of its methods, but when I run the test I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

      at node_modules\filesaver.js\FileSaver.js:22:15
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\filesaver.js\FileSaver.js:241:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src\components\MyComponent.js:3:44)
```

My test looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';

describe('<MyComponent /> test suite', function () {

   it('Smoke Test (Renders without crashing', () => {
       shallow(<MyComponent />)
   })
})
```

The component looks like:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

import { saveAs } from 'filesaver.js';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    handleFileDownload = (attachment) => {
        saveAs(attachment.blob, attachment.file_name)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button className="btn btn-default" aria-label="Download" onClick={() => this.handleFileDownload(this.props.attachment)}>
                <i className="icon icon-save" style={{ margin: '0' }} />
            </button>
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

How would I be able to write a shallow test with filesaver.js in my component or is there a way to mock the import of filesaver, as this is where the error happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently I wasn't using the correct file saver library. I used [this filesaver.js](https://github.com/mWater/FileSaver.js) project instead of the original and well maintained [filesaver.js from eligrey](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). With the later library everything works well and also shallow unit tests are possible without any issues.